# Profile User object displaying all user django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a CustomUser and a Profile app in my profile app i have following models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'),max_length=100)
    work = models.CharField(_('Position'),max_length=200)
    company = models.CharField(_('Company'),max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(_('Gender'),max_length=10)
    photo = models.ImageField(_('Profile Pic'),upload_to='images/',blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(_('Bio'),max_length=300) 
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

My main problem is when i include user field in forms it displays a drop down list of all user who are registered with the app.

And i want to show only loggedin user

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is better and saves a time:

```
user = MyUser.objects.filter(username__icontains=request.user)
form.fields['user'].queryset = user
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question specific to the form you are using, rather than the model. What you want to do is specify a queryset for the field `user`.

You may do this after instantiating your initial form. The following would go in your view, where you declare your form for get requests:

```
# Obtain set of authenticated users (see [1] below)
authenticated_users = []
users = User.objects.all()

for user in users:
    if user.is_authenticated():
        authenticated_users.append(user)

# Instantiate form and update `user` queryset
form = SomeForm()
form.fields['user'].queryset = authenticated_users
```

**[1]** I don't believe it's possible to filter the User object manager by whether a user is authenticated or not, unfortunately, so you must iterate through the queryset and check for each user. If anyone knows such a query, then I'd be happy to change my answer to it.

This will limit the dropdown to authenticated users.